# How to filter and get required data from a nested document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this structure in my DB.

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6386ef039775398be3620c76"),
    firstName: 'A',
    lastName: 'BA',
    age: 34,
    history: [
      { disease: 'fever', cured: true },
      { disease: 'malaria', cured: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6386ef239775398be3620c77"),
    firstName: 'AA',
    lastName: 'BA',
    age: 24,
    history: [
      { disease: 'cold', cured: true },
      { disease: 'thyroid', cured: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i'm tying to achieve is a query which will get me data like this:

Query

```js
 db.collection.find({$filter:{history:{$elemMatch:{cured:false}}}
```

Expected Result:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6386ef039775398be3620c76"),
    firstName: 'A',
    lastName: 'BA',
    age: 34,
    history: [
      { disease: 'malaria', cured: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6386ef239775398be3620c77"),
    firstName: 'AA',
    lastName: 'BA',
    age: 24,
    history: [
      { disease: 'thyroid', cured: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i have tried is

1.

```js
db.collection.find({$filter:{history:{$elemMatch:{cured:false}}}
```

2. 

```js
  db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        history: {
          $filter: { 
           input: "$history",
            as: "items",
            cond: { cured: false } 
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

3. 

```js
db.collection.find({history:{$elemMatch:{cured:true}}},{'history.cured':1})
```

But none of these queries are giving desired result,

Doubts/ Questions:

1. Is it possible to get expected result straight from a query?
2. Where my queries went wrong?
3. What material should i go through to cover more advance concepts related to this query?

Any help would be much appreciated.
My apologies if this question is too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to merge your query attempts to:

1. Get all documents that have an item with `cured`: false
2. `$filter` `history` array to include only such items

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      history: {$elemMatch: {cured: false}}
  }},
  {$set: {
      history: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$history",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.cured", false]}
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5SJYpdbmNWI)

Comment: You answer works, but can you please explain what your query does and why my aggregation query did'nt work?

Comment: 1. `$filter` does not work directly inside `find`, It is a pipeline command. 2. your syntax for `$filter` is wrong, and also the query is less efficient since it will try to filter documents without any matching item. 3. your second part `{'history.cured':1}` is projecting, not filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have amended my query `db.task1.aggregate([{$project:{history:{$filter:{input:"$history",cond:{$eq:["$$this.cured",false]}}}}}])` this query works, but i have a doubt, why should i do the `$match`?

Comment: @nimrodserok, yes even i have a doubt why should you do the `$match`, the above seem to work.

Comment: Since without it the query will be less efficient since it will try to filter documents without any matching item, and there can be many of those